# How to enable Eclipse auto-completion in application.yml for custom properties declared by @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, configuration, autocomplete

I made a simple class with configuration properties for my spring-boot project. Everything work as a charm (spring-boot catches options) except the fact that Eclipse doesn't recognize new properties as valid options in **application.yml** and highlights them as unknown.

Here is the class:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="server")
public class ServerProperties {
    private Integer delay;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter();
    // setters and getters were cut out for the sake of readability 

    public static class DataAdapter {
        private String baseUrl;
        private String targetCode;
        // setters and getters 
    }
}
```

Autocompletion does not work for those properties:

[image: Autocompletion does not work for those properties]

I added the dependency for Spring Boot Configuration Processor to **pom.xml** as recommended in [Spring.io reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor), but it does not work as supposed.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Tried to switch to *application.properties* but autocompletion still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring boot configuration processor works as an annotation processor during compilation time.

It's necessary to enable annotation processing for the Eclipse project and register the processor:

- Go to **Project / Properties** menu
- Open **Java Compiler / Annotation Processing**. Enable project specific settings and check "Enable annotation processing"
- Open **Java Compiler / Annotation Processing / Factory Path**. Check "Enable project specific settings"
- Click **"Add variable"** button, select "M2_REPO", click "Extend" and find **org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/x.x.x.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar** in the Maven repository, where x.x.x is version of your Spring Boot.
- Apply changes
- Recompile the project, or just touch and save the class with configuration properties to trigger partial recompilation.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me, the json file is still not generated by annotation processor :(

Comment: Do you have Spring Tools 4 - For Spring Boot installed in your IDE? As far as I remember, Application.yaml syntax highlighting is a part of the package.

Comment: I've installed but no way. There must be something i missed

Comment: I have just noticed that since last IDE update the list at Factory Path tab contains suspiciously many items. It's not like on the screenshot in my answer - there are several dozen positions now. Maybe my answer is outdated or you have some other issue in your system.

Comment: What JSON file are you waiting for? Does autocompletion for your custom values work?

Comment: The awful bit is that you have to bind the path to the annotation processor manually. And manually maintain it whenever you update the version of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding this to my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I had defined spring-boot-maven-plugin in my pom.xml when I met the issue. Maybe it was Eclipse/SpringBootFramework version-specific bug, fixed in later releases